# What are some good emacs font faces to manually set?

Tags: emacs, elisp, color-scheme, emacs-faces

There is alllll kinds of information out there about emacs color schemes, font locks, etc but I am having trouble getting where I want to be.  Basically I would like to know what are some of the best font faces to set in order to have a nice solid color theme which is a good cross language solution.  I am ending up with lots of language syntax (parens, brackets, operators, etc) not highlighted in some places when I expect them to be.

Below are the faces I am currently setting:

```
 font-lock-builtin-face
 font-lock-comment-face
 font-lock-comment-delimiter-face
 font-lock-doc-face
 font-lock-doc-string-face
 font-lock-function-name
 font-lock-keyword-face
 font-lock-negation-char-face
 font-lock-preprocessor-face
 font-lock-string-face
 font-lock-type-face
 font-lock-variable-name-face
```

What if any major faces am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do it like this. Choose a [colour-theme](http://code.google.com/p/gnuemacscolorthemetest/) that looks "okay" and when you're doing some work and find something unsatisfactory, `customise` that face to suite your taste.

I once knew someone who actually did an `xlsfonts` and opened an `xterm` for each one to decide which one he wanted to use while coding. Not thing kind of way I'd like to spend my time. :)

Comment: Is there some simple way to find out what faces are applied to a region?  I keep running into stuff I would like to change (or highlight to begin with), but don't have any easy time tracking it down.

Comment: Not an entire region (since there might be multiple faces in there) but if you do an `M-x` `customize-face`, it will by default prompt you with the face your cursor is on. Try it.

Comment: You're welcome. YOu can also do an `M-:` `(text-properties-at (point))` if you want.

Comment: C-u C-x = will give you all the font overlays at point in a Help buffer

Answer (score 0):

[zenburn](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/zenburn.el) is a beautiful [color theme](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme). I use the [terminus](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/) font on [debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/console-terminus).

Answer (score 0):

anyhow, I give up trying to use best font in GUI system. I revert to Raster Font, use in DOS Prompt / if it is in Linux, a TTY. Now that is so simple :)

My main workstation is Windows. There is (off course) native Win32 GUI version of Emacs, but I prefer to run it in DOS Command Prompt, using `I am using emacs -nw`. Using a few trick (write app that draw black border around screen edges), a found it able to make an illusion that it is in a console mode.

I love console mode :)